# response.write is not working asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

On button click event after inserting data I want to show message that data is inserted successfully.
***Here is my code***

```
if (com2.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1)
        {
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Request Submitted Successfully!')</script>");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('There is some error. Please enter again')</script>");
        }
```

It was working fine until I put code for empty textboxs after insertion in same event soon after above code. ***here is code***

```
foreach (var control in this.Controls)
        {
            TextBox tb = control as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

now textbox empty after data insertion, data is also inserting but no popup message is showing. Where is problem

Comment: So it doesn't work after you put in the redirect?

Comment: Take out the redirect and see if the alert box shows up.

Comment: @JackMarchetti when I take out it shows up

Comment: @DavidG yes it does not work

Comment: Well running a redirect, you are changing pages so Javascript won't get a chance to run on the page.

Comment: @DavidG then what should I do. I also want to empty textboxes and also want to show message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on your logic, but instead of having the server perform the redirect, do it on the client side after the call to `alert`:

```
if (com2.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1) {
    Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Request Submitted Successfully!');window.location='Default.aspx';</script>");
} else {
    Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('There is some error. Please enter again');window.location='Default.aspx';</script>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")` is run at the server level so you'll never give the client side a chance to render the javascript and therefore you won't ever see what your Response.Write is outputting.

Why don't you have an `<asp:Label>` control that will show the message you're looking for.

So, instead of a javascript message you could do:

```
tb.Text = String.Empty; //clear the textbox
label.Text = "Success Message.";  //show the message
```

It's been awhile since I've used WebForms but this should work if you have Viewstate enabled.  You might also want to look into UpdatePanels for this.

Comment: then what should I do. I also want to empty textboxes and also want to show message

Comment: I have not another way to empty text boxes and show popup message?? I don't want to use label.